Wifi not working following upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
This might be a similar question (Issue with Wireless Network Connection on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS). But my case is a bit different since this is an upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu running in parallel with Windows 11 from a separate dedicated partition. Following the upgrade the Wi-Fi stopped working with Ubuntu. I couldn't find the issue. Will highly appreciate any assistance. TIA
Below are the diagnostics:
(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ uname -r
6.8.0-40-generic

(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble


(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ lspci | grep -i network
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)

(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: 20:1e:88:6d:a7:c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=77.ad46c98b.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.u ip=192.168.0.142 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:605528c000-605528ffff

(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; p>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-09-23 02:14:12 IST; 4min 38s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1345 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 38061)
     Memory: 14.8M (peak: 15.8M)
        CPU: 563ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1345 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

(base) xander@xander-workstation:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i wifi
[    4.049413] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    4.049488] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.051166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x20000302 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    4.051188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev a0f0/0074, rev=0x351, rfid=0x10a100
[    4.058602] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    4.059153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 77.ad46c98b.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.535833] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351
[    4.658771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B5, rfid=0x10a100
[    4.724989] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 20:1e:88:6d:a7:c2
[    4.746424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    5.565638] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0

https://i.sstatic.net/fz7OyKA6.png


I ended up doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04. It's working now. But it was a ton of work!
